# How to play OGV inside iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, video-streaming, ogg

I have simple website that contains Ogg Video files accessible via URLs. How can I play that files from inside iphone app?

Answer (score 1):

## You can't

Convert the file to an MP4.